# Is there a way to read/print the activations of the hidden layers of a Neural Network in Stable Baselines?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

A central requirement for the project I am working on is being able to read the activations of the neurons in the hidden layers of the PPO2 models that I trained using the Stable Baselines library.
[Here](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/247) is a very related question. I would like to print them as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571756/how-can-you-get-the-activations-of-the-neurons-during-an-inference-in-tensorflow).
The closest I came to this is by doing this:

```
print(model.get_parameters())
```

This only prints the weights and biases but not the activations at prediction. I tried to edit the files of the Stable Baselines library but to no avail.
I have also tried

```
print(model.policy)
```

and this returns <class 'stable_baselines.common.policies.MlpPolicy'> as this only refers to the type of policy I am using. If there is no way to do this effectively, would it be easy to migrate my simple environment and train with another library? Would appreciate any help/suggestions I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way, which does not require from you to override pytorch's methods, is to **attach a forward hook**. I think I found [here](https://gist.github.com/Tushar-N/680633ec18f5cb4b47933da7d10902af) the code exactly for your problem. However you still need to define a [custom policy](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html), where you paste all that hook attachment, but that should be not so hard in your case.